# Validating XML against JSON

Tags: java, json, xml, xsd

I am looking to automate validating JSON instances against XML instances. What would be a good way to achieve this? I was thinking of mapping fields but then again this would just solve the problem say for one instance and the script would need to be updated for each instance.

Are there any libraries in Java that can aid in this?

Comment: Do you mean validating JSON against XSD?

Comment: No, I would like to check the values of the properties in an XML document (instance of a XSD) against a JSON file that should also contain those values, albeit not in a tree structure

Answer (score 1):

**No**, use [XML Schema (XSD)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/) for validating [***XML***](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/); use [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) for validating [***JSON***](http://www.json.org/).

If you're looking to parse from XML to JSON (unmarshal) or serialize JSON to XML (marshal), see [JSONIX](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix).

You may be using ***validate*** in an unconventional sense which would be satisfied by parsing from XML to JSON using JSONIX for comparison with other JSON.